# How to get json value in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have two tables in a database, `package` and `categories`.

`package` has a field `category_id` that contains data in this form `["1","11"]` and shows `categories` data in the form of a checkbox.

Now, I want all the data from `package` where `category_id` equal to `categories` `id`.

Here's my code :

```
public function archive_packages(Request $request, $slug){
    $title='Archive Packages';
    $para='';
    $slugs='archive-packages';
    $categoryRow = Category::where('slug',$slug)->first();
    $categoryID = $categoryRow->id;
    $package = Packages::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(category_id, \'["11"]\')')->get();
    dd($package);
    return view('pages.archive-packages',compact('title','para','slugs','package'));
}
```

I'm getting the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION
>   pre.JSON_CONTAINS does not exist (SQL: select * from `packages` where
>   JSON_CONTAINS(category_id, '["11"]'))

Comment: upgrade your mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a laravel method to do this, more details [here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#json-where-clauses)

So please try:

```
Packages::whereJsonContains('category_id', '11')->get();
```

If your mysql version does not support `json_contains` and you cannot upgrade it, then try this query:

```
Packages::where('category_id', 'like', '%"11"%');
```

Comment: I have an array of ids stored as json, tried this myself and it worked. Don't forget the quotes because without them it does not work, so 11 won't work but '11' will. Otherwise tell me what do you get and I can try to help.

Comment: (2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION pre.json_contains does not exist (SQL: select * from `packages` where json_contains(`category_id`, "11"))

Comment: Please check if the version of mysql that you use `json_contains` function exists.

Or try my edited code.

Comment: kindly guided more if we replace 11 to variable like $categoryID that contain number  like 11 , 1 , 5 etc

Comment: I will suggest that you upgrade your mysql version, because `like` will return results even if one of the `category ids` exists in the array. I don't know if that's your intention. And in order to pass a variable replace `'%"11"%'` with `'%"'. $categoryID .'"%'`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a built-in method json_encode() to easily encode arrays into JSON string format. We can implement it as: 
this we can use in laravel as well

$array = array('laptop','earphones','mouse');
return json_encode($array);

However, newer versions of Laravel also has a its own json() method which automatically sets relevant Content-Type and encodes JSON data:

$array = array('laptop','earphones','mouse');
return response()->json($array);

Comment: Your answer is completely unrelated to the question.

Comment: Yeah, I dint follow the description, On summery of question gave answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Example JSON:

[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "first_name": "Anthony",
    "last_name": "Ross",
    "language": "english",
    "grade": 1
  }
]

If you have multiple values in json then you can try a loop like,

```
foreach($target as $target_result){
  echo $target_result->id;
}
```

If you have only one record then try,

```
$target = Var::where('first_name', '=', $request->input('jsonArr'))->first();
return $jsonArr->id
```